# Getting filenames from a directory, put it into file, then zip it (UNIX)

Tags: unix, zip, pipe, io-redirection

Okay - so I've been trying all day today to see if this is possible.

In my case, I have a cache folder contains 1 million of cache files (and yes it's impossible to open). So for housekeeping, I'd like to delete those that has not been accessed since 120 days and log whatever was deleted. Managed to clean up around 200K files with this line:

```
find thisfolder -name "pattern*" -type f -atime +120 -exec rm -f {} \; -fprint /home/myfolder/logs/deleted_cache.txt 2>&1
```

But then, I ended up with a log file (deleted_cache.txt) about 50MB. That doesn't do housekeep any favor. So I was thinking to zip it up, hoping we could clear more space.

Read about the I/O redirection, piping, and zip; and after several attempts, it seems impossible to do it in a line. Is bash script the only way to do it?

Please enlighten me. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this command:

```
find thisfolder -name "pattern*" -type f -atime +120 -delete -printf '%f\n' | gzip > deleted_cache.gz
```

- `-delete` delete files
- `-printf` print file names to stdout
- `gzip` compress stdin

---

Note: I only test it in Ubuntu.